# Android studio display errors. but build successfully and work fine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, error-handling

Unresolved reference on `CalculationsUtils`

`val t5String = timeStringFromSeconds(CalculationsUtils.t5!!.toInt())`

But build and run successfully.

`CalculationsUtils` is a kotlin object.

[image]

Comment: Try to invalidate cache/restart

Comment: Have you tried restarting Android Studio and clean project?

Comment: Yes, I tried with restart android studio and also the clean project. The issue is still the same

Comment: file-->invalidate caches/restart in android studio